# count appearances of string from list in each pandas dataframe row

Tags: python, regex, pandas, count

I am trying to count the number of times a substring in my column `words` matches with a string in my list list_words and create a new column with the related value - `df['Score']`.

If my list of words contains 'dog' and 'answer', then then the first value for `df[Score]` would be 2, the second would be equal to 2, the third 1, the fourth 0.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(["What is the answer - dog is", 
                   "the answer isn't here, but the answer is 42" , 
                   "dogs are nice", 
                   "How are you"], columns=['words'])

list_words = ['dog', 'answer']
```

I am not really venturing in the coding solution here because of I have little familiarity with these types of task...

Comment: use `print (df['words'].str.count('|'.join(list_words)))`

Comment: Hi there, thanks for this. Is there a way to add a column that shows what are the substring/string that the df['words'] and list_words have in common?

Comment: Do you think `df['new'] = df['words'].str.findall('|'.join(list_words))` ?